# Angular - ng-pattern - Horas

Tags: angularjs

No código abaixo preciso fazer com que o ng-pattern receba 1 ou dois números, sendo que, o formata seja em horas, ou seja, nó mínimo 0 ou 01 e no máximo 24.

`<input type="text" step="any" value="" ng-model="" min="0" max="24" ng-pattern="/^([0-2]{1}[0-9]{1}$/">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar esse *pattern*:

```
/^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3])$/
```

Explicação:

```
^  "deve iniciar por"  
(  "início de um grupo"  
[0-1]?[0-9]  "zero ou um, seguido por zero a nove"  
|  "ou"  
2[0-3]  "iniciado por dois, seguido de zero a três, ou um número entre 20 e 23"
)   "fim do grupo"  
$   "fim"
```

Comment: Tks... Ricardo!! Deu para compreender muito bem.